# How can I reference counters for a specific environment only

Tags: environments, counters

```
\newenvironment{Group}[1]{
 \newcounter{#1}
}
```

but if I want to increase the counter, I have to specify the counter.

```
\begin{Group}{derp}
  \arabic{derp}
  \stepcounter{derp}
  \arabic{derp}
\end{Group}
```

I want to be able to do:

```
\being{Group}{foo}
  \IncAndShowCounter % keep a counter for this group only
\end{Group}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! I don't totally understand what you're trying to do. Do you want a single counter that's accessible inside each instance of your environment or do you want a counter per instance? Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 3):

As I said in the comment, I'm not sure exactly what you want to do, so here are two possibilities. In both cases, there's a `\IncAndShowCounter` macro that does what I think you want. But it's done differently for each case.

## One counter per environment, starting at 0.

Here, I allocate a single counter named `Group` and set it to 0 at `\begin{Group}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcounter{Group}
\newenvironment{Group}{%
    \setcounter{Group}{0}%
}{}

\newcommand*\IncAndShowCounter{%
    \stepcounter{Group}%
    \arabic{Group}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{Group}
\IncAndShowCounter\ first

\IncAndShowCounter\ second

\IncAndShowCounter\ third
\end{Group}

\begin{Group}
\IncAndShowCounter\ A

\IncAndShowCounter\ B

\IncAndShowCounter\ C
\end{Group}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can see that the counter resets inside each environment.

## One shared counter per type of `Group`.

Here, `\begin{Group}{foo}` will create a counter `foo` that will be accessible inside all such environments. `\begin{Group}{bar}` will have an unrelated counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newenvironment{Group}[1]{%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname c@#1\endcsname\relax
        \newcounter{#1}%
    \fi
    \newcommand*\IncAndShowCounter{%
        \stepcounter{#1}%
        \arabic{#1}%
    }%
}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{Group}{foo}
\IncAndShowCounter\ first

\IncAndShowCounter\ second

\IncAndShowCounter\ third
\end{Group}

\begin{Group}{bar}
\IncAndShowCounter\ x

\IncAndShowCounter\ y

\IncAndShowCounter\ z
\end{Group}

\begin{Group}{foo}
\IncAndShowCounter\ A

\IncAndShowCounter\ B

\IncAndShowCounter\ C
\end{Group}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice how the counter for the second `\begin{Group}{foo}` continues from the first.

Comment: Still have a bit of difficulty tho. I want to have each entry on the menu be prefixed with a counter, and a letter. So maybe entres would be E1... E6  and soups S1...S6

https://www.sharelatex.com/project/594cbdf1097fd8116d21b99e

Comment: Have the group environment take a second parameter that's the letter that you want and change the `\Entry` macro to display the letter and the counter value.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. thank you much